# get data from json by python flask

Tags: python, json, flask, request

I am sending this data to my python flask, and I would like help with how to receive it.
I get the arguments 'guid' and 'emp_empresa' perfectly, but json comes very werido.

data sent:
[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJuhx.png)

python code:

```
@app.route('/send_func_info', methods=["POST"])
def send_func_info():
    print(request.args.get('guid', ''))
    print(request.args.get('cod_empresa', ''))
    print(request.get_data())
    return jsonify({'return': 'ok'})
```

result:

```
abc
123
b"[\r\n    {   \r\n        cod_funcionario: '123',\r\n        nome_funcionario: 'toin',\r\n        funcao: 'carinha da \xc3\xa1gua'\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n        cod_funcionario: '456',\r\n        nome_funciona
rio: 'juanzim',\r\n        funcao: 'carinha da moto'\r\n\r\n    },\r\n    {   \r\n        cod_funcionario: '789',\r\n        nome_funcionario: 'marquinhos',\r\n        funcao: 'carinha da maratona'\r\n\r\n    }
\r\n]"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Aug/2020 15:40:00] "?[37mPOST /send_func_info?guid=abc&cod_empresa=123 HTTP/1.1?[0m" 200 -
```

Comment: try: `print(json.loads(request.get_data()))`

Comment: @GAEfan
I received this:
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 3 column 9 (char 21)`

Comment: @Felipe How about `request.get_json()` if not, `request.get_json(force=True)` which should work without a content type passed.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the method I use to get data usable for my applications

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json

@app.route('/create_servers', methods=['POST'])
def create_server():
    data = request.data
    data = json.loads(data)
    server_type = data["server_type"]
```

I'm currently using flask version: Flask==1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

JSON, which stands for JavaScript Object Notation, is an "open standard file format, and data interchange format". It is supposed to be human-readable, and it is very useful for transferring information from one place to another – it is **language independent**. It's often used in web applications like your flask one to exchange information from client to server, and it has started to replace XML (The X in AJAX) as the way that web apps do this.

JSON data is stored in attribute-value pairs, which is like a python dictionary: keys and values. In your HTML files it is likely you will use AJAX with JS, in which case, here is an example of how to do access JSON data, using [jQuery](https://jquery.com).

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getFeedback(source, dest) {
    $.getJSON(
              '/getfeedback',
              {source:source, dest:dest}
             ).done(function(data) {
                 $(dest).text(data.text)
             }).fail(function() {
                 $(dest).text(data.text)
           )};
```

And the view function:

```
from flask import jsonify, request

#flask stuff blah blah blah

@app.route('/delete')
def delete():
    try:
        source = request.args.get('source')
        dest = request.args.get('dest')
        return jsonify(result="success",text="Your request from {} to {} was successful".format(source, dest)
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

If successful the JSON will look something like this:

```
{
 "result":"success",
 "text":"Your request from #htmlId to #htmlId2 was successful."
}
```

If you bind the JS function to an HTML event, for example the click of a button, and you include the parameters of the place that you want feedback on and the place you want the feedback to go to (for example "#paragraph1" and "#header1"), you can send a GET request without reloading the page.